# Send the Acra report always

Tags: android, dialog, error-reporting, acra

I use for my Android app Acra as an error reporter. If the application crashes, i show the user a Dialog where he can wirte a comment. If the user clicks on abort i dont get a report message. My question now is:
is it possible to send a report if the user clicks on abort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No (as far as I'm aware).

You'd be best off using SILENT mode and having the crash report sent always, minus any user report.